# How/Where to log, audit, and alert on changes to Google Cloud Function code?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

How would our organization log, audit, and alert on any code changes (add, change, delete) to Google Cloud Functions to survive an external audit?  We've figured out how to do so on AWS (combination of CloudTrail and CloudWatch Events/Amazon EventBridge) and Azure (Audit log and Alerts under the Monitor service, although this is not as reliable as the AWS solution because some events do not seem to be picked up.  Azure even has this nice new service in preview called Application Change Analysis, but it does not alert, and it goes away when a function is deleted instead of reporting that it has been deleted.)

But how do we do the same thing with Google Cloud Functions?  How would we log and audit the creation/update/deletion of Cloud Functions and Cloud Function code?  How would we go even further and receive an alert whenever any of those conditions occur, just like we have proven can happen with AWS and (kind of, at least) with Azure?  Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you only deploy from a repo?  And, do all your auditing in the repo side of things?

Comment: That's an interesting thought, but can that be done with Google Functions?  If so, how?  And it still wouldn't audit the case where someone made an unauthorized change to function code from the Portal, would it?  Because Google Functions execute from stored versions in the Portal, don't they, and not directly from a Git repository?

Comment: You can set up the functions to pull from a repository instead of from the portal, and you can also set up auto-deployment -- then restrict access to modifying them in portal, and manage solely by pull requests.

If you're using github, you'll have to link first to Google Cloud repos.

Comment: Ah.  I see where you're going with that.  Let me check it out.  That would definitely help with the logging and auditing part of my request, but perhaps not with the alerting, unless alerts can be set up in GitHub.  Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing!  Github webhooks can be set up to trigger any kind of alerting you want -- you might need a Cloud Function to grab that and translate to an alert though :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Cloud Function audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/audit-logging). You can export the logs to PubSub, and then, you can do what you want on the event:

- Store them in BigQuery for the history
- Send an alert (email, slack message,...)
- Act: for example, perform a rollback to the previous code stored in the source repository
- ...

All depends on your security process and what do you want to do with the events.